# Concatenate numpy arrays in a list

Tags: arrays, list, numpy

I have a list with the following structure:

```
[array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6]), ...])
```

I want to generate the follwing numpy array:

```
array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], ...])
```

How is that accomplished?

Comment: np.array(your_list_of_array)

Comment: Just `np.array([array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6]), ...])`

Answer (score 1):

how are you doing?

I think the answer for what you are looking for is the following:

Let's assume the array you provided:

```
arr = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
```

Output: `[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]`

Then, you can do the following:

```
np.array(list(arr))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Hope it helps!

Take Care :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

```py
np_li = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
np.stack(np_li)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```